# Setting up alarm for android application using AlarmReceiver and OnBootReceiver

Tags: android, alarmmanager

I've browsed through numerous StackOverflow and Youtube tutorials to create an alarm service (to be used as a part of a larger app that I am building), yet it seems that all of them give different, non-working answers or rely on deprecated methods that do not work anymore.

My current issue with the following code is that when I reach the following code: `alrmMgr.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calendar.getTimeInMillis(), pendInt);` it does not seem to send the appropriate time to the alarm manager (it more or less always sends the current time).

However, I know for a fact that calendar.getTimeInMillis() gives me the time that I have set (the setAlarmText textView changes properly). I was wondering if anyone has any experience with this?

Furthermore, the `AlarmReceiver` class never seems to be called even though I was under the impression that the `AlarmManager` takes care of that for you.

Code is attached below:

```
public class AlarmStartPage extends Activity {
    AlarmManager alrmMgr;
    PendingIntent pendInt;                         
    private TimePicker alrmTimePicker;
    private static AlarmStartPage inst;
    Intent myIntent;
    private TextView alrmStatusView;`

    protected static AlarmStartPage instance() {
        return inst;                                        // returns an instance of the current Activity
    }

    @Override
    public void onStart() {
        super.onStart();                                    // calls the super classes onStart, and then sets the instance to the current one
        inst = this;
    }

    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_alarm_start_page);                             // sets the various buttons and other containers on the website
        alrmTimePicker = (TimePicker) findViewById(R.id.alarmTimePicker);
        ToggleButton alrmTogg = (ToggleButton) findViewById(R.id.toggleAlarmButton);
        alrmMgr = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);
        alrmStatusView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.alarmStatus);

        setVolumeControlStream(AudioManager.STREAM_ALARM);                              // sets the volume to be controlled to the audiomanager so that the user can control the alarm's volume
    }

    public void onToggleClicked(View view) {
        if (((ToggleButton) view).isChecked()) {
            Log.d("MyActivity", "Alarm On!");
            int hourToSet, minuteToSet;                                                 // if the toggle button is pushed, then it creates an alarm. Otherwise it cancels a previously created alarm
            Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 23)                                            // the code here and the one below in the else statement are identical except for which API they cater to
            {
                hourToSet = alrmTimePicker.getHour();
                minuteToSet = alrmTimePicker.getMinute();                               // gets the TimePicker's time that the user wants if using Android Marshmallow
            } else {
                hourToSet = alrmTimePicker.getCurrentHour();                            // gets the TimePicker's time that the user wants if using any Android Lolipop or below
                minuteToSet = alrmTimePicker.getCurrentMinute();
            }
            // this is the code to actually do the "magic" of the REM time
            int currhr = calendar.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);                        // gets the current time from the system's clock
            int currmin = calendar.get(Calendar.MINUTE);

            boolean lessThan90 = false;                                             // boolean to check if the current alarm is less than 90 Minutes away (1 REM cycle)
            int hrDiff = 0;
            int minDiff = 0;

            if (hourToSet >= currhr) {
                hrDiff = hourToSet - currhr;                                        // calculating the difference between the current hour and the hour of the alarm to get the difference in the time
                if (hrDiff == 0) {
                    if (minuteToSet > currmin)                                      // if the alarm is for after the current time, but same hour, then it is less than 1 hour away
                        minDiff = minuteToSet - currmin;
                    else {
                        hrDiff = 23;                                                // otherwise the alarm us for more than 23 hours away (same hour, but earlier time)
                        minDiff = 60 - (currmin - minuteToSet);
                    }
                } else {
                    if (minuteToSet > currmin)
                        minDiff = minuteToSet - currmin;
                    else {
                        hrDiff--;
                        minDiff = 60 - (currmin - minuteToSet);
                    }
                }

                if (60 * hrDiff + minDiff < 90)                                       // if prior to the 15 min shift, the alarm time is less than 90 minutes away, then it will be set as the alarm time
                    lessThan90 = true;
            }

            currmin += 15;                                                            // add 15 min to the current time, and below, change the hour and minute accordingly
            if (currmin >= 60) {
                currmin = currmin % 60;
                currhr++;
                if (currhr >= 24)
                    currhr = currhr % 24;
            }
            if (!lessThan90)                                                        // only if the alarm time is more than 90 minutes away, it will try to do this (which it will try to do
            {                                                                       // by defualt since lessThan90 is initalized to false (or it is set to true by the above if else statement
                if (hourToSet >= currhr) {
                    hrDiff = hourToSet - currhr;
                    if (hrDiff == 0)                                                // same logic as earlier, checks if the same hour as the alarm, then checks if the alarm is before or after the current time
                    {
                        if (minuteToSet > currmin)                                  // if the alarm is set for a later time (which means that it is less than 90 minutes away)
                            minDiff = minuteToSet - currmin;
                        else                                                        // otherwise the alarm is set for 23 hours and some minutes away
                        {
                            minDiff = 60 - (currmin - minuteToSet);
                            hrDiff = 23;
                        }
                    } else {
                        if (minuteToSet > currmin)
                            minDiff = minuteToSet - currmin;
                        else {
                            hrDiff--;
                            minDiff = 60 - (currmin - minuteToSet);
                        }
                    }
                } else if (hourToSet < currhr)                                        // if the alarm time is before the current time (then it must loop over midnight and restart from 0 again)
                    hrDiff = 24 - (currhr - hourToSet);
            }


            int totalMinutesInBetween = 60 * hrDiff + minDiff;

            if (totalMinutesInBetween < 90)                                         // if the total minutes between the alarm and the current time (after the 15 min shift) is less than 90 minutes
                lessThan90 = true;                                                  // it is less than 1 REM shift away

            if (!lessThan90)                                                        // If there are more than 90 minutes of difference, then a REM cycle is ACTUALLY possible
            {
                int possibleRem = totalMinutesInBetween / 90;                         // the possible amount of REM cycles between now and the alarm time
                for (int i = 0; i < possibleRem; i++) {
                    currhr++;                                                       // the time is altered by 90 minute cycles (looping around after 60 minutes or after 24 hours) to get the appropiate REM time
                    if (currhr >= 24)
                        currhr = currhr % 24;
                    currmin += 30;
                    if (currmin >= 60) {
                        currmin = currmin % 60;                                       // looping the minutes over 60
                        currhr++;
                        if (currhr >= 24)
                            currhr = currhr % 24;                                     // looping the hours after 24 hours
                    }
                }
                hourToSet = currhr;
                minuteToSet = currmin;
            }

            calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, hourToSet);                          // the calendar sets the final REM time
            calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, minuteToSet);

            myIntent = new Intent(AlarmStartPage.this, AlarmReceiver.class);
            pendInt = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(AlarmStartPage.this, 0, myIntent, 0);             // new intent as well as a pending intent to notify the system of the alarm (uses Alarm Receiver and Alarm Service)

            alrmMgr.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calendar.getTimeInMillis(), pendInt);                     // alarmmanager is used to set the alarm
            if (minuteToSet > 9)
                setAlarmText("An alarm has been placed for " + hourToSet + ":" + minuteToSet + " (in military time). If you shut down" +
                        " this app, please do not open it again until the alarm that you set is over (otherwise the alarm will reset itself).");    // alarm text is changed to notify the user
            else
                setAlarmText("An alarm has been placed for " + hourToSet + ":0" + minuteToSet + " (in military time). If you shut down" +
                        " this app, please do not open it again until the alarm that you set is over (otherwise the alarm will reset itself).");
        } else {
            alrmMgr.cancel(pendInt);                                                //cancels the current Intent (effectively stopping the alarm)
            stopService(myIntent);
            setAlarmText("The previous alarm was canceled.");                       // changes the text on the textbox under the time picker
            Log.d("MyActivity", "Alarm OFF");
        }
    }

    public void setAlarmText(String textToShow) {
        alrmStatusView.setText(textToShow);             // sets the text for the textbox below the TimePicker
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();                              // calls the super classes destroy method to destroy the activity
    }
}
```

AlarmReceiver:

```
public class AlarmReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {`

        Uri alarmUri = RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_ALARM);               //this will sound the alarm tone
        Log.d("Creating Alarm", "Used ALARM for ringtone " + alarmUri);
        System.out.println("logging that it got to this part");
        if (alarmUri == null) {
            Log.d("Creating Alarm", "Used the notification instead of alarm for ringtone");
            alarmUri = RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);
        }

        Ringtone ringtone = RingtoneManager.getRingtone(context, alarmUri);

        ringtone.play();                                                                        // plays the ringtone of the phone as the alarm

        Intent service_intent = new Intent(context, AlarmService.class);
        context.startService(service_intent);
        //ComponentName comp = new ComponentName(context.getPackageName(), AlarmService.class.getName());
        //startWakefulService(context, (intent.setComponent(comp)));                              // sends the notification message and wakes up the phone
        setResultCode(Activity.RESULT_OK);
    }
}
```

AlarmService.java:

```
public class AlarmService extends IntentService {
    private NotificationManager alarmNotificationManager;`

    public AlarmService() {
        super("AlarmService");
    }

    @Override
    public void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {
        sendNotification("Wake Up! Your alarm has been rung!!!!");                      // sends the notification to the phone that the alarm is ringing
    }

    private void sendNotification(String msg) {
        Log.d("AlarmService", "Preparing to send notification...: " + msg);
        alarmNotificationManager = (NotificationManager) this.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

        PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, new Intent(this, AlarmStartPage.class), 0);                        // creates the notification and sets the icon for the notification

        NotificationCompat.Builder alarmNotificationBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(
                this).setContentTitle("Alarm").setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher).setStyle(new NotificationCompat.BigTextStyle().bigText(msg)).setContentText(msg);


        alarmNotificationBuilder.setContentIntent(contentIntent);

        alarmNotificationManager.notify(1, alarmNotificationBuilder.build());
        Log.d("AlarmService", "Notification sent.");
    }
}
```

OnBootReceiver:

```
public class OnBootReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
    private static final int WAITING_PERIOD = 10000;    // 10 seconds (aka 10000 milliseconds)`

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent)
    {
        AlarmManager aMgr = (AlarmManager)context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);          // allows previously created alarms to still exist on bootup.
        Intent i = new Intent(context, AlarmReceiver.class);
        PendingIntent pI = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0, i, 0);

        aMgr.setRepeating(AlarmManager.ELAPSED_REALTIME_WAKEUP, SystemClock.elapsedRealtime(), WAITING_PERIOD, pI);
    }
}
```

Code can also be found on https://github.com/sahilmgandhi/REM.my/tree/master/app/src/main/java/com/sahilmgandhi/remmy

Any help would be appreciated.

**Edit:**

This is the solution we came up with in case if it helps anyone:

Nick: So the broadcast does start the service which runs the notification, but the issue is where the sound is supposed to be changed and it doesn't?

Nick: Ok so is there any reason you are having the sound play from the Receiver and not have the sound play straight from the notification object?  I think that would work

Me: Hmm, i was following several different tutorials and all of them seemed to have it in the receiver.

Nick: in the service sendNotification method try to change to this:

```
    private void sendNotification(String msg) {
    Log.d("AlarmService", "Preparing to send notification...: " + msg);
    alarmNotificationManager = (NotificationManager) this.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

    PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, new Intent(this, AlarmStartPage.class), 0);                        // creates the notification and sets the icon for the notification


    Uri soundUri = RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_ALARM);
    NotificationCompat.Builder alarmNotificationBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(
            this)
            .setContentTitle("Alarm")
            .setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher)
            .setStyle(new NotificationCompat.BigTextStyle().bigText(msg))
            .setContentText(msg)
            .setSound(soundUri);

    alarmNotificationBuilder.setContentIntent(contentIntent);

    alarmNotificationManager.notify(1, alarmNotificationBuilder.build());
    Log.d("AlarmService", "Notification sent.");
}
```

Nick: Pretty sure that's the correct way to do notification sounds now.. old way with Ringtone is probably deprecated. Comment the ringtone part out for now

Nick: And the correct way to run a service from AlarmManager is to have it fire a BroadcastReceiver which then starts your IntentService.

Nick: I forget exactly why that's the case.. but you definitely want to do it that way. I've thought about running everything in the receiver but its best to do it that way, alarm -> receiver -> IntentService with all the code in it

Comment: This might not be where the problem is, but try this first and see if it changes anything. Add `calendar.setTimeInMillis(System.currentTimeMillis());` right after this line: `Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();` in your `AlarmStartPage` activity.

Comment: Adding that line helped so that it no longer creates an alarm at the current time but rather at the time that is set by the TimePicker. Thank you! However for some reason even if I set a breakpoint in AlarmReceiver.java, the program never goes into it (even though an alarm does eventually ring and a toast is made).

Comment: Cool!  I added an answer post for that part of the question.  I don't totally understand what you mean about your AlarmReceiver, what exactly are you trying to accomplish?  I can hopefully figure it out.

Comment: Let me clarify. Once the alarm has rung, a toast is made telling the user that the alarm is ringing. This is done in the AlarmService class. However, the alarm that is run relies on the default notification noise rather than the default Alarm noise (which is what I try to change in AlarmReceiver.java). Yet the OnReceive method never seems to be called. None of the log statements ever get printed.

Comment: Ok.  I don't see a `Toast` being made anywhere in your code though?

Comment: Whoops, I meant notification, not toast (in AlarmService.java).

Comment: So to clarify, the alarm runs and fires at the correct time, but nothing in your BroadcastReceiver happens, therefore your service is never started?

Comment: Yep, that's right. My apologies for not wording it better earlier.

Comment: Ok lets first try this.  Change this line at the bottom of AlarmStartPage from: `PendingIntent.getBroadcast(AlarmStartPage.this, 0, myIntent, 0);` to this:   `PendingIntent.getBroadcast(AlarmStartPage.this, MorningReceiver.REQUEST_CODE,
                myIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);`  Then add this to your AlarmReceiver BEFORE the onReceive, like right after the first line of declaring the class:  `public static final int REQUEST_CODE = 111;` then uninstall/reinstall app and give it a try

Comment: Hey Nick, could we move this discussion to chat? My reputation is not high enough to start the chat, but it seems like we are almost all the way there (adding the above code did not do much of a difference however).

Comment: Um yeah chat where?

Comment: https://codeshare.io/29WVga

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get your alarm to fire at the correct time,  add this line after you instantiate your Calendar object in your `AlarmStartPage` activity:

```
calendar.setTimeInMillis(System.currentTimeMillis());
```

So your code should now look like this when you create your Calendar:

```
Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
calendar.setTimeInMillis(System.currentTimeMillis());
```

This will make sure the other Calendar parameters are set correctly, because before you had it just setting the hour/minute but the rest was not fully configured.